# Subseting a dataframe with shiny ignores specific rows

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app in which I want to subset the datatable displayed based on the user Input in the sidebar. The issue is that as you will see the 3 last rows of my dataframe are not displayed at all while all rows are selected. I suspect that this happens because the "DCH" exists 3 times instead of one but I do not know what happens with "LDP".

## DATA

```
Database<-c("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","DCH","DCH","LDP")
Organism<-c("Human","Human","Human","Human","Human","Human","Mouse","Rat","Human")
Unique_Drugs<-c(12672,5130,1425,3090,6100,2019,250,736,1182)
Unique_Targets<-c(3987,2175,842,2308,2413,1441,198,327,702)
Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug<-c("5.87 ± 6.72","2.60 ± 6.87","2.28 ± 3.76","3.29 ± 5.03","3.60 ± 5.21","6.28 ± 14.29"
                             ,"1.92 ± 1.83"
                             ,"4.11 ± 5.32"
                             ,"4.27 ± 8.25"
)
Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target<-c("11.63 ± 15.59",
                             "12.52 ± 23.93",
                             "10.71 ± 8.37",
                             "12.98 ± 17.57",
                             "23.44 ± 25.65",
                             "13.87 ± 34.23",
                             "8.20 ± 18.44",
                             "14.82 ± 9.36",
                             "17.43 ± 9.34"
)
Unique_Drug_Target_Associations<-c(
45276,
14598,
3599,
12439,
23048,
13872,
594,
2876,
3915)

db<-data.frame(Database,Organism,Unique_Drugs,Unique_Targets,Mean_S.D.Drugs_per_Target,Mean_S.D.Targets_per_Drug, Unique_Drug_Target_Associations)
```

## APP

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Stats Table"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("dbase")
    
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    DTOutput('tbl')
  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) { 
  output$dbase<-renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("base", label = "Specify dataset(s)",
                 choices = list("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","LDP"),
                 selected = c("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","LDP")
    )
  })
 
  df_subset <- reactive({
    a <- subset(db, Database == input$base)
    return(a)
  })
  
  output$tbl = renderDT(
    df_subset(), options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your code, you will see the following errors in your console:

```
Warning in `==.default`(Database, input$base) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

To solve this, you should replace the line

```
a <- subset(db, Database == input$base)
```

with

```
a <- subset(db, Database %in% input$base)
```

Since you want to check if the values in the column are in the vector `input$base`, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) for the documentation of this operator.  Hope this helps!